# Какой GRANT выдать схеме, чтобы она могла удалить партицию в другой схеме? ORA-01031

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, права, partition

Есть две схемы:

- `my_schema_1`
- `my_schema_2`

Есть таблица с партициями:

- `my_schema_2.my_table`

Я хочу от лица `my_schema_1` удалить партиции в `my_schema_2.my_table`. Сперва выдал права от лица `my_schema_2`:

```
grant all on my_table to my_schema_1;
```

Пытаюсь удалить из-под `my_schema_1`:

```
ALTER TABLE my_schema_2.my_table DROP PARTITION SYS_P00001 UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;
```

Возвращает ошибку:

> ORA-01031: привилегий недостаточно

Каких привилегий недостаточно? Я вроде бы выдал `ALL` на эту таблицу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насчёт, каких привелегий недостаточно, в гл. [ALTER TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877) сказано следующее:

> **Additional Prerequisites for Partitioning Operations**
>
> If you are not the owner of the table, then you need the **DROP ANY TABLE** privilege in order to use the *drop_table_partition* or *truncate_table_partition* clause.

Давать такие системные привилегии, скорее всего исключение. Лучше найти решение, где владелец схемы сам будет удалять партиции.

Если что, то так:

```
grant drop any table to my_schema_1;
```

Comment: Спасибо! Однажды я научусь нормально пользоваться штатной справкой ._. В свое оправдание скажу, что пытался гуглить) К сожалению, пришлось таки закинуть джоб в схему с таблицей. Аудит начнет казни, если выдать такие мощные права на другую схему)

Comment: Ну да, или схема уже имеет достаточно привелегий, или что-то не так с дизайном. Давать такие привилегии, исключение.

Comment: 0xdb, Приветствую! У меня к вам личный вопрос, поэтому призываю в комменты. Хочется получить официальную корочку от оракла, но у них такое многообразие курсов, что подкрадывается паралич выбора. Могли бы вы порекомендовать какой-либо для обычного линейного Oracle Developer'а, который пилит объекты в базе? Может у вас в организации есть какие-то стандарты куда на обучение отправляют или типа того? о.О

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов Для личных вопросов в профиле телеграм есть. Не знаю, чем  смогу помочь. _Может у вас в организации есть какие-то стандарты_, у меня нет никакой организации. Можно подготовится самостоятельно, если спонсора оплатить курсы нет. Тесты тоже стоят немало, но это уже вам решать, оправдает себя или нет. Как первый шаг - "Oracle PL/SQL Developer Certified Associate", это два особо не сложных теста.